# How do I use a variable with special characters in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I have this variable in my bash script:

```sh
var="\'?"\"'\"
```

but when I type `echo $var` I get nothing. I want `echo $var` to return `"\'?"\"'\"`. What should I do here?

Comment: In addition to correct quoting when setting the variable, you should also, double-quote when you *use* the variable (e.g. `echo "$var"` instead of just `echo $var`). See ["I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else). BTW, [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at spotting mistakes like this.

Comment: @DuduKrem : _I want echo $var to return "\'?"\"'\"_  ... I guess you mean .... to **output** that string, not to **return** it. In this case you have to store this string in the variable first: `var=\"\\\'\?\"\'\\\"; echo $var`.

Comment: did it worked ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

````
var="'''?\"\"\""
or
var='```?"""'


echo "$var"
````